# Vertical auto-scrolling of a list group

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create auto-scroll a list, an exact replica of the list found at the right side of [this](https://plantyourpick.com/) website, you need to scroll down a bit, i found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30664261/how-to-create-an-auto-scrolling-list) but i observe the scroll is not smooth.

any help with this, with purely CSS, would be much appreciated.

My html is below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">List of Donors</div>
      <ul class="list-group donors">
        <li class="list-group-item" *ngFor="let flag of (flags | async)">
          <p>{{ flag.name }} {{flag.address}}</p>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code:

```
.list-group-item {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #666;
}

.donors {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    -webkit-animation: autoScrolling 5s linear infinite;
    height: 20em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes autoScrolling {
    from {
        margin-top: 0;
    }
    to {
        margin-top: -20em;
    }
}
```

N:B I am CSS beginner, a working css trick would be appreciated.

Comment: show us your code please

Comment: @TheDev, i have attached the code for the list i need to style

Comment: where is the css code?

Comment: @TheDev, i have update my question with the  Css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will look at the code on website you're referring to, you will spot that they use [Obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee) `<marquee>` tag. So if you don't want to use this unrecommended way to achieve your goal, you might consider Javascript solutions, like this:

[Javascript Marquee to replace <marquee> tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337330/javascript-marquee-to-replace-marquee-tags)

Of course, you still can use CSS hacks to do it, for [example](https://www.html.am/html-codes/marquees/css-marquee.cfm) `@keyframes` animations, but I'd consider this as a bad code, and I'm not sure if it's better than using outdated HTML tags.