# Moving Marquee/Moving Text Down in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move down  or Moving Text in HTML, but I can't seem to be able to, move it anywhere. I added a color command to change the color of the text, but it seems like that just moved, it all the way to the top.

```html
<marquee style="color:blue" behavior="scroll" scrollAmount="15" width="1100" height="28" onMouseOver="this.scrollAmount=14" onMouseOut="this.scrollAmount=12"> 
<b> WELCOME TO USBUDNI! ENJOY YOUR STAY!</b>
</marquee>
```

That is the HTML that I use for the text.

Comment: Marquee is outdated, don't use it in 2019. See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55094443/vertical-auto-scrolling-of-a-list-group/55094493#55094493

Answer (score 0):

add this style to  tag.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```